# Maximization algorithm for the product function in R^2

Tags: calculus, optimization, game-theory

Is there any smart way to maximize the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2_{++} \to \mathbb{R} $, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ constrained to a given convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$ ?

Does exist some remarkable cases in which there are smart solutions to this problem?

(note: $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0 \land y \geq 0 \} $)

Comment: $xy$ is increasing in both $x$ and $y$, so we know it is optimized on the boundary. Parameterize the boundary we are now optimizing the one-dimensional problem $f(t)=x(t)y(t)$. Do you have a more specific example?

Comment: You're right! Let's now say that this convex subset is a convex hull containing (0,0) (a,0) and (0,b) for some a,b>0 and some other points of R^2 (I know it's a baroque definition, I mean the subset is given by the intersection of some lines and the x=0 and y=0 axes (a graph would be much more clear)). Any idea to improve the algorithm you proposed?

Comment: Simply parameterize it. You can use $ay+bx=ab$ or $y=b-bx/a$ for example. Then just maximize $x(b-bx/a)$ over the interval $[0,a]$.